# Does netty.io support netconf protocol?

Tags: netty, ietf-netconf

I am trying to create a netconf client. I am already using netty.io jar in the project. I want to know if netty.io support netconf or is there any plan for that ? Is there any way I can write neconf client using netty.io ?

I wrote simple ssh java program, but it does not connect to netconf on a particular port. So I am thinking to use netty.io library to do this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is not included in Netty but you could write your own codec for it. Netty is protocol agnostic, so this should be no problem.

Answer (score 1):

But the problem you might face if you go with netty is that it does not have a ready made implementation for SSH and as of [RFC 6241](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6241)
mandates SSH as a transport option.